# Error in django form handling via ajax request

Tags: python, ajax, django

this is my post method of class based view:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'delete' in request.POST:
            owned_license_id = request.POST.get('id', '')
            if owned_license_id:
                try:
                    OwnedLicense.objects.get(id=owned_license_id).delete()
                    return HttpResponse("success")
                except:
                    return HttpResponse("failure")
        elif 'add' in request.POST:
            form = OwnedLicenseForm(request.POST or None)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
            else:
                errors = form.errors
                return HttpResponse(json.dumps(errors))
```

and my javascript script function in html file:

```
function add_new_license(btn, id)
    {
       alert($("#add_license_form").serialize())
       $.ajax({
            url: "/manage/licenses/{{mls_signup_code}}/{{agent_id}}/" + id + "/",
            type: "post",
            data: $("#add_license_form").serialize(),
            success: function(response) {
            console.log(response)
            }
        })

    }
```

`add_license_form` is my form id. Now in my view whenever I try `form.is_valid()` it always result `False` and there is no error in form.error.

am i missing something here?

This is my request.POST:

```
<QueryDict: {'add': ['add'], 'charge_amount': ['0.02'], 'is_suspended': ['on'], 'start_date': ['07/21/2015'], 'tier_type': ['5'], 'auto_renew': ['on'], 'deactivation_time': [''], 'product_license': ['2'], 'is_trial': ['on'], 'reactivation_time': [''], 'tier_id': ['1'], 'payment_day': ['1'], 'expiration_date': ['2015-08-24']}>
```

Comment: You can  do `print request.POST` in the view, and see what the value of `request.POST` is - One issue i see in the code is, `OwnedLicense.objects.get(id=owned_license_id).delete()` would throw an exception. You probably mean `OwnedLicense.objects.filter(id=owned_license_id).delete()`

Comment: What is the result of `form.errors`? That should tell you why it's not valid.

Comment: Looks like you're still missing your request.POST info in your update but if form.errors is empty then chances are it's never reaching that part of the code or your POST data is empty and `request.POST or None` is returning `None`

Comment: my request.POST is non-empty, is there anything else i should try??

Comment: I don't see anything wrong then. I would open up a shell or insert `pdb; pdb.set_trace()`  right after form is being declared and debug.

Comment: exactly! neither do I, but what i can see is an empty form.error  object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84205/discussion-between-austin-and-ajay-gupta).